# How to create large PDF / Convert file size PDF with terminal ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 20.04, pdf

I have question

How to create large PDF / Convert file size PDF with terminal ubuntu ?

if i have file pdf size 1mb, and i want that file to be 50mb or 100mb, but not add contents in pdf file please help me i am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Why would someone want to do that? Please check [What is the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are talking about a PDF created from an image file, and you want to have it in higher resolution, try this:

```
convert -density 300 source.jpg destination.pdf
```

(you might have to first install ImageMagick and then possibly enable PDF generation as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69535567/6756843 )

Comment: thank you nice .